# What method is used to diagonalized this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

> \begin{align*}
>   \left(
>   \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
>      3  & -2  &  2  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     -2  &  3  & -2  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>      2  & -2  &  3  & 0 & 0 & 1
>   \end{array}
>   \right)
>   &\xrightarrow{S_2 \to S_2 + S_3}
>     \left(
>   \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
>      3  & 0 &  2  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     -2  & 1 & -2  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>      2  & 1 &  3  & 0 & 0 & 1
>   \end{array}
>   \right)
>   \\
>   &\xrightarrow{Z_2 \to Z_2 + Z_3}
>   \left(
>   \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
>     3 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>     2 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 1
>   \end{array}
>   \right)
>   \\
>   &\xrightarrow{S_3 \to S_3 - \frac{2}{3} S_1}
>   \left(
>   \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
>     3 & 0 & 0           & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 2 & 1           & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
>     2 & 1 & \frac{5}{3} & 0 & 0 & 1
>   \end{array}
>   \right)
>   \\
>   &\xrightarrow{Z_3 \to Z_3 - \frac{2}{3} Z_1}
>   \left(
>   \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
>     3 & 0 & 0           &  1            & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 2 & 1           &  0            & 1 & 1 \\
>     0 & 1 & \frac{5}{3} & -\frac{2}{3}  & 0 & 1
>   \end{array}
>   \right)
>   \\
>   &\xrightarrow{S_3 \to S_3 - \frac{1}{2} S_2}
>   \left(
>   \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
>     3 & 0 & 0           &  1            & 0 & 0 \\
>     0 & 2 & 0           &  0            & 1 & 1 \\
>     0 & 1 & \frac{7}{6} & -\frac{2}{3}  & 0 & 1
>   \end{array}
>   \right)
>   \\
>   &\xrightarrow{Z_3 \to Z_3 - \frac{1}{2} Z_2}
>   \left(
>   \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
>     3 & 0 & 0           &  1            &  0            & 0 \\
>     0 & 2 & 0           &  0            &  1            & 1 \\
>     0 & 0 & \frac{7}{6} & -\frac{2}{3}  & -\frac{1}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}
>   \end{array}
>   \right).
> \end{align*}
>
> Es gilt also
>   $$
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>      1            &  0            & 0           \\
>      0            &  1            & 1           \\
>     -\frac{2}{3}  & -\frac{1}{2}  & \frac{1}{2}
>   \end{pmatrix}
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>      3  & -2  &  2  \\
>     -2  &  3  & -2  \\
>      2  & -2  &  3
>   \end{pmatrix}
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>     1 & 0 & -\frac{2}{3}  \\
>     0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2}  \\
>     0 & 1 &  \frac{1}{2}
>   \end{pmatrix}
>   =
>   \begin{pmatrix}
>     3 & 0 & 0           \\
>     0 & 2 & 0           \\
>     0 & 0 & \frac{7}{6}
>   \end{pmatrix}.
> $$
>
> [(Original image here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZV99.jpg)

Could someone please explain or give me a hint in the right direction as to what method is being used to diagonalize this matrix.

I understand that performing these operations is equivalent to multiplying with an elementary matrix so we want to them simultaneously with the identity matrix.

I dont quite understand the logic behind the first step and why the result at the end holds.

Comment: The picture doesn't make it clear.  The method seems to be finding a *basis of eigenvectors* corresponding to distinct eigenvalues.  When a symmetric matrix has two eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues, they are necessarily orthogonal.  Then it is very easy to use that basis to produce a diagonal matrix, similiar to the original symmetric matrix.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the goal is not only to find a diagonal matrix that is similar but one so that A=Q^t *D * Q

Comment: Yes, this is what we usually mean by "diagonalizing a (real) symmetric matrix".  The orthogonality of a basis of eigenvectors makes it straightforward to construct the orthogonal matrix $Q$ that accomplishes a "change of basis".

Comment: The procedure is, I think, a bit misleading for diagonalization.  It requires us to know in advance what the three eigenvalues are and that they are distinct (in this case $3,2,7/6$).  In other words, we know the destination we want to drive the elimination procedure to from some considerations not shown in the picture.

Comment: I think I get it now, but the method works without knowing the eigenvalues. After each row operation A=EA one can perform the same columm operation, which would be equivalent to A=AE^t. One only changes the identity matrix after the colum operations though. If one ends up with a diagonal after following this procedure one should arrive at the sought after dexomposition right?

Comment: Your Comment highlights what I think is misleading.  Ordinarily the Gauss-Jordan elimination procedure on nonsingular $(A|I)$ would be directed to producing a (reduced) row-echelon form $(I|A^{-1})$.  Yet $I$ is obviously not the diagonal form similar to $A$.  So more is required than "one ends up with a diagonal" following an elimination procedure (elementary row operations).

Comment: @hardmath: This method **does not** diagonalize $A$ as an endomorphism, but as a bilinear form: The values 3, 2, 7/6 are **not** (necessarily) the eigenvalues of $A$, and the resulting matrix on the right is **not** (necessarily) orthogonal. No additional information about $A$ is nedded for this procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 2 & 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 3 &  - 2 \\ 
2 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
We choose a sequence of elementary matrices $E_j$ and perform steps:
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j \; ,  $$
which maintain:
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 2 & 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 3 &  - 2 \\ 
2 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
2 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 2 & 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 3 &  - 2 \\ 
2 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 7 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
3 &  - 2 & 2 \\ 
 - 2 & 3 &  - 2 \\ 
2 &  - 2 & 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 1):

Any real symmetric matrix $A \in \operatorname{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is congruent to a diagonal matrix $D \in \operatorname{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. therere exists an invertible matrix $S \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $S A S^T = D$.
This is a matrix version of the fact that for every symmetric bilinear form $\beta \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ on a finite dimensional real vector space $V$ there exists a basis of $V$ which is orthogonal with respect to $\beta$.

One can find such matrices $D$ and $S$ by using *simultaneous column and row operations*:

- We apply an elementary column operation to $A$, resulting in a matrix $A'$.
  The matrix $A'$ will (in most cases) not be symmetric again.
- To fix this we then apply the corresponding elementary row operation to $A'$, resulting in a matrix $B$.
  The matrix $B$ is then again symmetric.

By repeatedly applying the above two steps we bring $A$ into a lower triangular form (similar to how the Gauß algorithm brings a matrix into row echolon form).
Because the matrix stays symmetric throughout this process (after applying both column and row operations), the resulting symmetric matrix $D$ will also be upper tringular, and therefore a diagonal matrix.

A suitable invertible matrix $S$ with $S A S^T = D$ can then be calculated by applying the the elementry row operations from above in the same order to the identity matrix.

Instead of first calculating $D$ and then $S$, one can also calculate both at the same time, by applying to the elementary row operations to both $D$ and $S$ at the same time.
(This is similar to computing the inverse of a matrix $A \in \operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ via the Gauß-algorithm, by transforming $A$ to the identity matrix via elementary row operations while simultaneously applying the same row operations to the identity matrix $I$ to calculate $A^{-1}$.)
This is precisely what is done in your example:

- In the first iteration, the third column is added to the second column.
  Thus we get $(A \mid I) \to (A' \mid I)$ with $A'$ not being symmetric.
- We now apply the corresponding elementary row operation to both matrices, adding the third row to the second row.
  We get $(A' \mid I) \to (B \mid Q)$.
  Note that $B$ is again symmetric and that $Q A Q^T = B$.
- In the second iteration, we substract $2/3$-times the first column from the third column.
  We get $(B \mid Q) \to (B' \mid Q)$ with $B'$ not being symmetric.
- We now apply the corresponding elementary row operation to both matrices, subtracting $2/3$-times the first row from the third row.
  We get $(B' \mid Q) \to (C \mid R)$.
  Note that $C$ is again symmetric and that $R A R^T = C$.
- In the third iteration, we subtract half of the second column from the third column.
  We get $(C \mid R) \to (C' \mid R)$ with $C'$ not being symmetric.
- Now we apply the corresponding elementary row operation to both matrices, subtracting half of the second row from the third row.
  We get $(C' \mid R) \to (D \mid S)$.
  Note that $D$ is again symmetric and that $S A S^T = S$.

Since $D$ is also diagonal the algorithm terminates.

An explanation of this algorithm can be found in Gerd Fischer’s *Lineare Algebra*, section 5.7.6 (the book is in German), and a similar overview as above can be found in [these notes](https://github.com/cionx/lineare-algebra-2-review-ss-17/raw/master/notes.pdf), section 6.2 (also in German).